# Scraping linkedin public profile with selenium and phantomjs in Python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I try getting the body of https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/paul.
On my local, I work under UBUNTU 14.04 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, phantomjs 2.1.1 , selenium 2.53 and python 2.7 and my script works fine.
But when I send my script to the server which is Debian Jessie x86_64 GNU/Linux (with the same version of phantomjs, selenium and python as my local), there is nothing under the body tag of the document.

This is my code *main.py*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import sys

    def initial(nom):
        #browse to linkdin url
        url = "https://www.linkedin.com"
        browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ssl-protocol=any', '--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
        browser.get(url)

        #set first name input value
        inpt = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
                    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "first"))
            )
        inpt.send_keys(nom)

        #submit form
        submit = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "search"))
                    )
        submit.click()

        #print result content page
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "professionals"))
                 )    
        print(browser.current_url) 


    def main(args):
        nom = args[1]
        initial(nom)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main(sys.argv)
```

This is the output of request when running on server

```
    <html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  // Parse the tracking code from cookies.
  var trk = "sentinel_org_block";
  var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
    if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkCode=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {
      trk = cookies[i].substring(8);
    }
  }

  // Get the protocol for the redirect url.
  var protocol = "http:";
  if (window.location.protocol == "https:") {
    protocol = "https:";
  } else {
    // If "sl" cookie is set, redirect to https.
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
      if ((cookies[i].indexOf("sl=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 3)) {
        window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  // Get the new domain. For touch.www.linkedin.com or tablet.www.linkedin.com
  // we strip "touch." and "tablet.". For international domains such as
  // fr.linkedin.com, we convert it to www.linkedin.com
  var domain = location.host;
  if (domain.substr(0, 6) == "touch.") {
    domain = domain.substr(6);
  } else if (domain.substr(0, 7) == "tablet.") {
    domain = domain.substr(7);
  } else if (domain.charAt(2) == ".") {
    domain = "www" + domain.substr(2);
  }

  window.location.href = "https://" + domain + "/uas/login?trk=" + trk + "&session_redirect=" +
      encodeURIComponent(protocol + "//" + domain +
      window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.search(window.location.host) +
                                  window.location.host.length));
}
</script>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

This is a log output when I run the script on server

```
[INFO  - 2016-09-06T12:57:11.706Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 39646
[INFO  - 2016-09-06T12:57:12.467Z] Session [6dbb4db0-7431-11e6-85da-e9ae670edee0] - _decorateNewWindow - page.settings: {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":false,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.2 Safari/534.34","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2016-09-06T12:57:12.467Z] Session [6dbb4db0-7431-11e6-85da-e9ae670edee0] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2016-09-06T12:57:12.467Z] Session [6dbb4db0-7431-11e6-85da-e9ae670edee0] - CONSTRUCTOR - Desired Capabilities: {"platform":"ANY","browserName":"phantomjs","version":"","javascriptEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2016-09-06T12:57:12.467Z] Session [6dbb4db0-7431-11e6-85da-e9ae670edee0] - CONSTRUCTOR - Negotiated Capabilities: {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.2","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.0.4","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2016-09-06T12:57:12.468Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 6dbb4db0-7431-11e6-85da-e9ae670edee0
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:13.436Z] Session [6dbb4db0-7431-11e6-85da-e9ae670edee0] - Page at 'https://www.linkedin.com/' - Console Error (msg): TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'a.bind(a,!1)')
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:13.437Z] Session [6dbb4db0-7431-11e6-85da-e9ae670edee0] - Page at 'https://www.linkedin.com/' - Console Error (stack): [
  {
    "file": "https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=69w33ou4umkyupw2uqgn7za7w",
    "line": 2,
    "function": ""
  }
]
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:13.941Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166633906
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:14.545Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166634498
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:15.280Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166635239
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:15.998Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166635959
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:16.706Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166636661
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:17.406Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166637366
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:18.104Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166638067
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:18.826Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166638783
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:19.529Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166639491
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:20.224Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166640189
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:20.936Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166640888
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:21.635Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166641597
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:22.344Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166642298
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:23.039Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166643004
[ERROR - 2016-09-06T12:57:23.744Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1473166643702
```

Comment: The error suggests that you're not using PhantomJS 2.x, but rather 1.x. Are you really sure that Selenium uses the correct version of PhantomJS?

Comment: No, I don't sure to know which version of Phantomjs can be working fine with selenium 2.53 but it works on my local.

Comment: Thanks to @Artjom , I check phantomjs but I installed this one from npm and it prints 2.1.1 as version when checking version from Terminal